# c++ pass content of a vector as parameters to a function

Tags: python, c++

In python we can do something like this:

```
def test(a, b, c):
    return a+b+c

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = test(*x)
```

Can we do something similar to this in C++?

Answer (score 2):

The solutions proposed so far are based on a run-time iteration over function arguments, which incurs some cost. They also assume argument types are the same. If the number of arguments is known at compile time (it usually is), then a different solution would be like

```
template <typename F, typename T>
auto tuple_call3(F&& f, const T& t)
-> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<0>(t), std::get<1>(t), std::get<2>(t)))
   { return std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<0>(t), std::get<1>(t), std::get<2>(t)); }

struct test
{
   template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
   auto operator()(const A& a, const B& b, const C& c)
   -> decltype(a + b + c)
      { return a + b + c; }
};

int main()
{
    auto x = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3);
    auto y = tuple_call3(test(), x);
    cout << y << endl;
}
```

which has no run-time cost and works with heterogeneous argument types. I have no time to further develop this now, but to make it fully generic we'd need to

- Use universal references (like `F&&`) and forwarding (like `std::forward<F>(f)`) everywhere, including function arguments of course.
- Make `tuple_call` variadic. For this, if `L` is the size of the tuple (via [tuple_size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size)), we would need to generate sequence `0,...,L-1` at compile time (see e.g. function `range` [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44546/very-basic-tuple-implementation/44832#44832)). If `N...` is this sequence, use `std::get<N>(t)...`.
- Make it work with plain functions. Now `test` is a function object, and could be a lambda as well, but a plain function should either not be a template, or have its template arguments explicitly specified (upon `tuple_call`); otherwise its type `F` can't be deduced.

It would be great if all this were integrated in the C++ language but it is not (yet). At least there tools to make something roughly equivalent. By the way, I don't know what is the run-time cost of the equivalent in Python.

Answer (score 1):

At least, I think below code is close to your python code

```
int test(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
}

std::vector<int> x = { 1, 2, 3 };
int y = test(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. For example

```
#include <numeric>
#include <initializer_list>

int test( std::initializer_list<int> l )
{
    return std::accumulate( l.begin(), l.end(), 0 );
}

int y = test( { 1, 2, 3 } );
```

Or

```
int test( const int a[] )
{
    return a[0] + a[1] + a[2];
}

int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int y = test( a );
```

Or

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
int test( const std::vector<int> &v )
{
    return std::accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), 0 );
    // or return v[0] + v[1] + v[2];
}

std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
int y = test( v );
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no one-liner that transforms a container to the required parameters of a function.  This is due to the fact in C++ that function calls are handled during compile time while content of containers are known at runtime.

So my closest example would be

```
int test(int a, int b, int c) { return a + b + c; }

std::vector<int> x = { 1, 2, 3 };
int y = test(x[0], x[1], x[2]);
```

Mind you that since you have to take care in python that the number of elements in the container match with the expected arguments, the given example is not very usable.

Comment: Check my compile-time alternative (depends on what we mean by "container" and how `x` is defined).

Comment: @iavr: I saw your answer and there is some similarity, but my answer is about converting a container to parameters of a conventional function.  But based on the different answers, the question leaves room for interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are talking just about transforming a literal to a vector-like object, see [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) (C++11)

```
template <typename T>
void test(std::initializer_list<T> aList) {
    //do stuff with aList, for example std::accumulate,
    //or make a vector with it: std::vector<T> v(aList);
}

auto x = {10, 11, 12};
test(x)
```

but if you need to use a function which have "normal" parameters, you need to jiggle with va_args, see example in [va_arg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_arg/), so the answer probably would be "No".